# Files disappearing from Dropbox

Tags: meteor

Suddenly (at about the same time as upgrading to 0.9.0) my machine seems to be deleting older versions of Meteor-based apps, from anywhere on the machine including Dropbox. Thousands of files are disappearing. It is a little terrifying. Am I doing something wrong? Can I get them back?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve deleted files from dropbox.com . There is a small trash bin icon "Show deleted files" and you can recover them.

I don't know what your files are, but if a program is deleting them according to their format for instance, you may want to zip/rar them prior to put them into the box. This can also save space if the goal is to archive them.